# ¿Cómo guardar los índices al iterar sobre un array?

Tags: python

Quería consultarles cómo se pueden obtener los índices originales de una lista filtrada.

Partiendo de:

```py
original = [1 ,2, 10, 2, 1, 10, 20, 30]                 # Lista original
filtrada = [items for items in original if items < 3]   # Filtro items < 3

print ("Lista original: ", original)
print ("Lista filtrada: ", filtrada)

# Output:
# Lista original:  [1, 2, 10, 2, 1, 10, 20, 30]
# Lista filtrada:  [1, 2, 2, 1]
```

La pregunta del millón es si hay alguna forma que devuelva el índice original de cada elemento de la lista filtrada.

El resultado que busco para este ejemplo sería:

```
idxListaFiltrada = [0, 1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `for i in range(len(original))` y guardar el índice `i` si `original[i] < 3`.

Otra forma similar a lo anterior es con [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
filtrada = []
idxListaFiltrada = []
for idx, item in enumerate(original):
    if item < 3:
        idxListaFiltrada.append(idx)
        filtrada.append(item)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Más claro imposible! Un genio.